# How to detect power saving mode of graphic card in windows application?

Tags: c++, windows, gpu, power-management

I have an application using an OpenGL window that works ok, but someone detects  that if the graphics performance is configurated as power saving, the screen doesn't show any render, it only show a black screen that could be interpreted as a UI bug.

I was wondering if there is a way to know if my application is running in power saving mode, since that configuration implies to use the less powered machine's gpu I don't know if it is possible to use the winAPI. In example I have a Intel GPU and a Nvidia GPU, so the power saving mode use Intel's GPU.

I want to send a warning message or turn off the power save mode.

The winAPI function GetSystemPowerStatus seems to be related with the battery, so it doesn't work for my purpose.

**References**

- https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/faq/gpu-110
- https://asapguide.com/graphics-performance-preferences/

Comment: It seems like you should identify and fix the bug in your program that's causing it to fail in power saving mode, rather than try to disable power saving mode. Your users won't thank you for messing with their settings.

Comment: The problem is probably that you're trying to use some GL extension the Intel GPU doesn't support. You might miss some capability test in your code. If you're not doing really fancy stuff, also the Intel GPU should be able to display things properly, just a bit slower.

Comment: Ok, you are right guys the issue was that I was using texture2D function that has been deprecated and is no longer supported by intel graphics. I change the code to use just texture(...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was trying to use texture2D that the Intel GPU doesn't support. I just change it to texture, as recommended in comments